# Demo account for Outlook add-in

Tags: office-store

In order to use the add-in which I'm currently developing you will have to log in with a username and a password.
In your requirements, you ask for a demo account in order to make all the validations.

My question is - can you supply the email which you are going to use in order for me to open an account for it?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Comment: @piet.t Where do you suggest to get this information from?

Comment: That question should be answered by the Office Store support team but they keep ignoring the issue and the bad customer experience it creates.